# Copy Spreadsheet Ready CSV to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I would like to display some comma separate values to a user in JavaScript (but really, language is not the point here) and allow them to paste that right into their spreadsheet program, much like SQL Server Management Studio does.

For example, in SQL Management Studio (and other programs), if I select the columns here, I can paste those right into Excel, no formatting or importing needed.

[image: SQL Server Copy]

[image: Paste Results]

If I just output CSV as it is:

[image: Regular CSV Copy]

It puts everything in one row:

[image: Paste Results of CSV]

What do I need to do to my output to make it so when I copy it, I can just easily paste it into a spreadsheet program?

Comment: In Excel, you can use the [Text to Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-2cd989db-2b1f-4d89-b17b-534250ff9905) method - does that help?

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I want to just be able to copy and paste without needing any additional methods. I know it's possible, as other apps can do it.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I am interested in doing the same.